# IE resolution issue

Tags: c#, html, razor, responsive-design

Here is the question i posted and got the answer.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17780797/set-contents-of-page-according-to-browser-resolution

Every thing is working fine in Firefox and chrome.But Need is that it must work in IE.But It always gives QR Code under Captcha. Here is what I have changed my code.

```
  <div style="border: 1px solid lightgrey; border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px; width: 825px">
        <ul id="holder" style="display:inline-block; list-style-type: none;">

             <li style="display:inline-block; list-style-type: none">
                <div class="captcha" >
                    @Html.Captcha("Refresh", "Enter Captcha", 5, "Is required field.", true)<div style="color: Red;">@TempData["ErrorMessage"]</div>
                </div>
            </li>

            <li style="display:inline-block; list-style-type: none;">
                <div id="qrcode" class="qrcode">
                    <img src="@Url.Action("QrCode", "Qr", new { url = Model.ShortUrl })"  onclick="AppendURL('@this.Model.ShortUrl')"/>
                </div>
            </li>

        </ul>
    </div>
```

And JS code is :

```
  window.onresize = getWindowWidthHeight;
window.onload = getWindowWidthHeight;
function getWindowWidthHeight(event) {

    var width = window.innerWidth;
    var height = window.innerHeight;
   // alert(width);
    //alert( $(window).width());
    var firstLi = document.getElementById('holder').children[0];
    if (width > 600) {
        firstLi.style.display = 'inline-block';
    } else {
        firstLi.style.display = 'list-item';
    }
};
```

Kindly help.Thanks in advance.

Comment: which version of ie, you could easily google that "ie display inline-block" returns as first result [this](http://www.keynet.at/blog/story/html-inline-bloecke-in-internet-explorer-co/)

Comment: @luk2302 I am using IE8

Comment: @CodeCaster its not duplicate.I am not asking for that question again.

Comment: the maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9110646/ie8-display-inline-block-not-working) might help, easily found via google too, learn to use that ressource.

Comment: It is entirely the same subject, just with some extra criteria, or even caused by changes made to your code according to the answers you received there. Please update your old question.

Comment: @CodeCaster ok.Thanks I will take care of this next time

Comment: @luk2302 i have tried this but it cant solve my problem.